# Custom row cell in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm looking to use a custom row cell to label my data.

| Basketball | Baseball | Golf | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | $50 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | $75 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | $150 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | $225 |

The table I have is above. What I'm trying to do is below:

OUTPUT:

| Sport | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Basketball | 200 |
| Baseball | 300 |
| Golf | 375 |

I can get the sum of each sport but I'm having trouble making an alias for each sport on the output table (The first column)

How would I go about that? I've done an alias for a column header, but never for a row cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a UNION of three separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
select   game
        ,sum(cost*flg) as cost
        
from t 
     cross join lateral (
     values 
            (basketball, 'basketball')
           ,(baseball, 'baseball')
           ,(golf, 'golf')
                        ) t2(flg, game)
group by game
```

| game | cost |
| --- | --- |
| golf | 375 |
| baseball | 300 |
| basketball | 200 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FY8JPSLO)

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION with different WHERE conditions:

```
select sport, sum(cost)
from 
( 
  select 'Basketball' as sport, cost
  from the_table 
  where basketball = 1
  union all
  select 'Baseball', cost
  from the_table 
  where baseball = 1
  union all
  select 'Golf', cost
  from the_table 
  where golf = 1
) t
group by sport;
```